# subversion not working with pycharm

Tags: python, subversion

In pycharm, there is an option to upload changes to a remote svn repository.

However, it does not ask for password. How do I provide it?

Comment: try to save credentials on ~/.subversion/auth

Comment: do I need to do that from pycharm? those folders are empty

Answer (score 2):

> it does not ask for password.

Maybe because of caching:

you can disable credential caching. To disable caching for a single command, pass the --no-auth-cache option:

```
$ svn commit -F log_msg.txt --no-auth-cache
Authentication realm: <svn://host.example.com:3690> example realm
Username:  mark
Password for 'mark':

Adding         newfile
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 2324.

# password was not cached, so a second commit still prompts us

$ svn delete newfile
$ svn commit -F new_msg.txt
Authentication realm: <svn://host.example.com:3690> example realm
Username:  mark
[...]
```

Or, if you want to disable credential caching permanently, you can edit your runtime config file (located next to the auth/ directory). Simply set store-auth-creds to no, and no credentials will be cached on disk, ever.

```
[auth]
store-auth-creds = no
```

As source you can make use of this [Link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s02.html).

Answer (score 1):

From the PyCharm documentation regarding [authenticating to Subversion](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/authenticating-to-subversion.html):

> Subversion server does not require user authentication on every
>   request. When you use the Subversion integration from within PyCharm,
>   you only need to answer the authentication challenge of the server, if
>   it is required by the authentication and authorization policies. The
>   successful authentication results in saving your credentials on disk,
>   in `~/.subversion/auth/` on Unix systems or `<USER HOME>/.subversion_IDEA`
>   on Windows and OS X.
>
> When an authentication challenge comes from the server, the
>   credentials are sought for in the disk cache; if the appropriate
>   credentials are not found, or fail to authenticate, the users is
>   prompted to specify the login name and password.
>
> If necessary, you can opt to delete all credentials stored in cache,
>   for http, svn and ssh+svn protocols.